# Block with search box in header

Tags: search, blocks

I need to create a block with a search box in header in order to allow users to search for a the specific content type that is shown in that block, but I don't know how to do this.

I've attached one photo to show what I need.

[image: sketch]

Comment: All you need to do is creating a view block with an exposed search function. A walk through on how to do something like this is available at http://summapro.com/drupal-tutorials/learning-exposed-filter-views-search-and-filter.